# Why doesn't npm moment timezone work? (America/Toronto)

Tags: reactjs, npm

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I can't get the current time from Toronto Canada, I get an added 4 hour.

Here is my code:

```
 var moment = require('moment-timezone');
    const [date, setDate] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        var mom = moment.tz(moment(), 'America/Toronto');
        setDate(mom);
    }, []);
```

Then I add `date` to my bd and get the wrong hours (4 hours to early).

I use react and npm moment.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Then I add date to my bd` - what does this mean and where does it happen?

Comment: What happens if you do `moment.tz(moment().toISOString(), 'America/Toronto');` ?

Comment: @ksav I create an order and I want to have an attribute dateOrder with current time in Toronto, Canada. So I build an order in react and save it to my bd. I works ( it create the order) but with the wrong time).

Comment: @ksav when I try your suggestion it doesn't register the order in the bd I guess it's because of the format. I try to simply subtract 4 hour to ```moment``` but it doesn't work either with the function ```subtract```. Do you know how to do ?

Comment: I don't know what a `bd` is.